# JqChart guru seeking. Radar chart can not get the actual maximum data value

Tags: jquery, charts, radar-chart, jqchart

Here's the sample code with my result [jsfiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/cyrilkong/XeEWn/)!

My question is how could I make the maximum point manually instead of 500 in the radar's label.

It's just a table-SVG converter I am doing.

```
series_data
```

is a Array come from table each of sources <td>.

Normally I want a max point of datas is 100, but it always count me with 500, whats the matter?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add numeric values in the series.data arrays.

In your code change this line:

axes_datas.push($(this).text());

with:

axes_datas.push(parseFloat($(this).text()));

Comment: Oh yes, you save my life. This is painful when dead loop in other-side thinking.